# How do I convert a list of integers to ints?

Tags: python

I'm making a program to sort numbers from lowest to highest as long as the numbers are under 300, but I can't figure out how to change the user input into a list. Here's my code:

```
List1=[]
List2=[]
var=1
thing=input("Insert numbers here")
List1.append(thing)
while var < 300:
    for that in List1:
        if that < var:
            List2.append(number)
    var = var + 1
print(List2)
```

When I run the code, it says that in the 8th line, a string can't be compared with an int.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the user's input formatted?

Comment: Where did `number` come from?

Comment: Just a simple `int()` cast should do, along with some exceptions.

Comment: just try int(that) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/python-parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your variable `that` is a string. This is why you can't compare it against an integer. If you need to convert your string to an [int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) you can simply wrap it with [int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)(your_variable_here).

For example

`if int(that) < var:`

This would convert the string `that` to an [integers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) (number). The benefits of converting it to a integer is that you can compare it against other integers, and use basic [arithmetic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Basic_arithmetic_operations). That wouldn't be possible if you used a string.

An even better solution would be to directly store the input as an integer.

```
List1.append(int(thing)) # We wrap the keyboard input with int
```

Also, if you are running Python 2.x I would recommend that you use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), instead of [input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't seem to be in any loop, I don't see how you can have more than one entry in the list.. Perhaps you could have space seperated numbers entered? Using **python 3**, this could be minimized like so (minus error handling):

```
nums = [x for x in list(map(int, input("Enter numbers: ").split())) if x < 300]    
nums.sort()
```

Or..

```
nums = input("Enter numbers: ") # Get the number string
nums = nums.split() # Split the string by space character
nums = list(map(int, nums)) # call int() on each item in the list, converting to int
nums.sort() # sort the list of numbers
nums = [x for x in nums if x < 300] # remove any numbers 300 or over.
```

Input/output:

```
Enter numbers: 1 5 301 3000 2
[1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm kind of a nube at python. Could you possibly explain what you just did?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the numbers separated by commas, the following single line will work:

```
>>> sorted(list(input("Enter numbers: ")), reverse=True)
Enter numbers: 1, 2, 3
[3, 2, 1]
```

To remove numbers < 300:

```
>>> sorted([num for num in input("Enter numbers: ") if num < 300], reverse=True)
Enter numbers: 1, 301, 299, 300, 2, 3
[299, 3, 2, 1]
```